# detect mouse scroll and call a function

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

For `http://www.rawkey.co.in` I am using fullpage.js.
Now instead of clicking the arrow buttons to iterate through the pages, I want to use the mouse scroll wheel to iterate through the pages. Can someone please help? 
from `http://www.rawkey.co.in/js/jquery.fullpage.js`:

```
    $(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      if (delta > 0){
        function moveSlideRight(section){
            moveSlide('right', section);
        }
      } // going down
      if(delta < 0){
        function moveSlideLeft(section){
            moveSlide('left', section);
        }
      } //going up
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Might be so much more easier to help if you did provide a jsfiddle or something representing your config. Well...

Comment: The easiest and most secure way to do so is by making use of the [Scroll Horizontally extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html) provided by fullpage.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need help with this, see my working snippet below (don't mind the lack of CSS :P).

You'll have to take note that, with the js as it is:

- Scrolling up while on first slide will go to the "Previous" section (if existing).
- Scrolling down while on last slide will go to the "Next" section (if existing).

You might have to tweak it according to your other needs ;).

**EDIT**

- Corrected error message *"$(...).moveSection[Up|Down] is not a function"* since call to those functions is not needed.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  //Navigation
  menu: '#menu',
  lockAnchors: false,
  anchors: [],
  navigation: false,
  navigationPosition: 'right',
  navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide', 'thirdSlide', 'fourthSlide'],
  showActiveTooltip: true,
  slidesNavigation: true,
  slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

  //Scrolling
  css3: true,
  scrollingSpeed: 700,
  autoScrolling: true,
  fitToSection: true,
  fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
  scrollBar: false,
  easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  easingcss3: 'ease',
  loopBottom: false,
  loopTop: false,
  loopHorizontal: true,
  continuousVertical: false,
  interlockedSlides: false,
  offsetSections: false,
  resetSliders: false,
  fadingEffect: false,
  normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
  scrollOverflow: false,
  scrollOverflowReset: false,
  scrollOverflowOptions: null,
  touchSensitivity: 15,
  normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
  bigSectionsDestination: null,

  //Accessibility
  keyboardScrolling: true,
  animateAnchor: true,
  recordHistory: true,

  //Design
  controlArrows: true,
  verticalCentered: true,
  sectionsColor: ['#0061ff', '#ff0000'],
  paddingTop: '0',
  paddingBottom: '0px',
  fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
  responsiveWidth: 0,
  responsiveHeight: 0,

  //Custom selectors
  sectionSelector: '.section',
  slideSelector: '.slide',

  lazyLoading: true,

  //events
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {},
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {},
  afterRender: function() {},
  afterResize: function() {},
  afterResponsive: function(isResponsive) {},
  afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {},
  onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {}
});

$('.slide').on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) {

  if (delta == 1) { // Up

    // Move to previous section if this is first slide in slider
    if ($(this).is(":first-child"))
      return true;

    $('.fp-prev').trigger('click');
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
  } else { // Down

    // Move to next section if this is last slide in slider
    if ($(this).is(":last-child"))
      return true;

    $('.fp-next').trigger('click');
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.5/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.5/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">hey hey hey</div>
  <div class="section slider">
    <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">Ho ho ho</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's gonna cause issues in many laptops with kinetic trackpad. Such as Apple ones. Far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most secure way to do so is by making use of the [Scroll Horizontally extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html) provided by fullpage.js.

This way:

- You make sure it will be 100% compatible with any other features & extensions.
- You make sure it won't brake with fullpage.js updates or fullPage.js API changes.

Right now your the proposed solution by @Bladepianist:

- Won't work on touch devices.
- Will create issues in kinetic scrolling devices.
- Won't be compatible with other extensions.
- Won't work when removing the arrows.